# rvm does not import gem path

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, osx-yosemite

I’m running on Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10 Beta 3, I did a fresh install of rvm (removed everything I could think of and reinstalled the whole thing.

Attempting to run a scripts I had working on Mavericks.

```
Maxims-MacBook-Air:AppleSampleCodeWorker maximveksler$ gem install restclient
Successfully installed restclient-0.10.0
Parsing documentation for restclient-0.10.0
Done installing documentation for restclient after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
Maxims-MacBook-Air:AppleSampleCodeWorker maximveksler$ which irb
/Users/maximveksler/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/irb
Maxims-MacBook-Air:AppleSampleCodeWorker maximveksler$ irb
2.1.2 :001 > require 'restclient'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- restclient
    from /Users/maximveksler/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/maximveksler/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/maximveksler/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/irb:11:in `<main>’
```

Path looks normal

```
Maxims-MacBook-Air:AppleSampleCodeWorker maximveksler$ env | grep GEM
GEM_HOME=/Users/maximveksler/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2
GEM_PATH=/Users/maximveksler/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2:/Users/maximveksler/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global
```

Also the gem is installed

```
Maxims-MacBook-Air:AppleSampleCodeWorker maximveksler$ file /Users/maximveksler/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/restclient-0.10.0/lib/rest_client.rb
/Users/maximveksler/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/restclient-0.10.0/lib/rest_client.rb: ASCII C++ program text
```

So what am I missing ?

Comment: I think you might be confused [`restclient`](https://github.com/thoom/restclient) seems to be a commandline only gem, (unless I'm mistaken?) are you thinking of [`rest-client`](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client)?

Comment: @MikeH-R You’re right. gem install rest-client solves the problem. This makes me feel extremely frustrated as rest-client also installed a command line binary called restclient. Is there a better way to detect which gem provides which ‘require’ clause? I’d appreciate that as an answer that I could accept to close this issue with. Thank you for help, now this works again https://github.com/sugarso/AppleSampleCode and this is the code behind the scenes https://github.com/sugarso/ScrapingTheApple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your link [here](https://github.com/sugarso/ScrapingTheApple), there is an error in your syntax. It should be `require 'rest_client'` rather than `require 'restclient'`. The reason that your version still works is as you said because there is a file called restclient.rb which is used as the source for the additional restclient binary that the gem supplies (which is against regular naming convention, you should file an issue with the github).

Now because you require this file (`restclient.rb`) which is used to set up an environment that already has `RestClient` available, it is effectively the same as requiring `rest_client`. It may however have unintended consequences so you should probably stick to the convention outlined in the documentation.

This is all from reading the documentation [here](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) and glancing at the files [here](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/tree/master/lib). Does that make sense? I worried it was unclear as the two files are very similar.

Comment: Thanks https://github.com/sugarso/ScrapingTheApple/commit/dbd9df7fa6a2caf123e581a2fdaa81251028805f